# Jpa Repository save inside a for loop

Tags: web-development, spring, hibernate, jpa

I have this requirement:

- Csv Upload (using opencsv)
- Should display if the record is inserted (if it doesn't exist in the db) or updated (if it exists). 
  Eg.: 5 records inserted 2 records updated.

Usually I use `repo.saveAll(entityObjList)` to save all the entries.

Since I have to keep track of number of updates and inserts, I came up with using the `repo.save(entityObj)` method inside the for loop which is not greatly appreciated.

Is there any other way to approach this problem ? Any suggestion is welcome.

Comment: What does "which is not greatly appreciated" mean?  Did you get some pushback from your team/corporate?  What was the feedback?

Comment: Most relational database systems will return the number of records affected from a query.  Why don't you just fix your `saveAll` method so it returns that number?

Comment: @RobertHarvey Well we decided not to use the `JpaRepository.save()` inside the for loop because of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49869277/spring-data-save-vs-saveall-performance). The `JpaRepository.saveAll()` seems to return the last saved object. It is not my implementation of the same.

Comment: If you can't fix the saveAll method, you'll have to decide whether the performance or the number of records returned is more important.

Comment: Do the entities have Ids generated by the database, or are you assigning Ids to new entities prior to saving?

Comment: @GregBurghardt Yes, there is sequence running so no assigning of ids prior to saving.

Comment: Since you're using Spring: unless you're explicitly building your own JpaRepository implementation, calling `saveAll` from the default `SimpleJpaRepository`... just does a for loop and calls `save` on every entity therein. So doing a for loop and saving each thing... is exactly the same performance as saveAll.

Answer (score 1):

If the count of the inserts/updates is the only thing you need, quick (and possibly dirty) solution might be to keep using `saveAll` method and selecting the count of the entities in the database before and after the `saveAll` call -- all wrapped in a transaction of course. Knowing the size of the collection passed to `saveAll` you can calculate how many entities were created and how many were updated in the database.

Answer (score 0):

Since the Ids of the entities are numeric and generated by the database on insert, loop over all of the entities. If the Id of an entity is 0 or null, then it will be an `INSERT`. If the Id of an entity is greater than zero (or what ever the minimum number of the sequence is) then it will be an `UPDATE`.

You would loop over the entities to be saved and tally up in the inserts and updates, then call the `saveAll` method on the repository, where you can get the performance boost over calling `save` for each entity individually.

Summing the inserts and updates might be better off in a service layer or class representing a use case, rather than the repository. The additional loop to detect the inserts and updates will add overhead, but you should be fine performance-wise until you reach the 1,000s of entities.

Even then, measure the performance to see if the decrease is small enough to make this feature worthwhile.

Answer (score 0):

From `org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.SimpleJpaRepository`

```java
/*
     * (non-Javadoc)
     * @see org.springframework.data.repository.CrudRepository#save(java.lang.Object)
     */
    @Transactional
    public <S extends T> S save(S entity) {

        if (entityInformation.isNew(entity)) {
            em.persist(entity);
            return entity;
        } else {
            return em.merge(entity);
        }
    }
//...
@Transactional
    public <S extends T> List<S> save(Iterable<S> entities) {

        List<S> result = new ArrayList<S>();

        if (entities == null) {
            return result;
        }

        for (S entity : entities) {
            result.add(save(entity));
        }

        return result;
    }
```

Basically, you can mimic what `save(Iterable)` does. Use the annotation @Transactional in your repository method and choose the propagation strategy that best works for you. `REQUIRED` should be enough.